# Serve Geotiff file using Geotiff.js

Tags: javascript, geotiff-tiff, hillshade

I have this geotiff file of hillshade which I am trying to render on HTML using Geotiff.js https://geotiffjs.github.io/

but it doesn't seem to render anything.

[image]

If I inspect chrome console, it does print console logs without any error but image is just black. Is there a mistake in parameters?

[image]

Here is my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geotiff"></script>
    <script src="d3-marching-squares.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
(async function() {
    let origin = [700, 600];
    let size = [500, 450];
    const tiff = await GeoTIFF.fromUrl("url");
    let image = await tiff.getImage(0);
    const width = image.getWidth();
    const height = image.getHeight();
    const tileWidth = image.getTileWidth();
    const tileHeight = image.getTileHeight();
    const samplesPerPixel = image.getSamplesPerPixel();

    let rasterData = await image.readRasters({window: [origin[0], origin[1],
                                                       origin[0] + size[0], origin[1] + size[1]],
                                                       samples: [0]});
                                                       
    rasterData = rasterData[0];

    let data = new Array(size[1]);
    for (let j = 0; j<size[1]; j++){
        data[j] = new Array(size[0]);
        for (let i = 0; i<size[0]; i++){
          data[j][i] = rasterData[i + j*size[0]];
        }
    }


    let intervals = [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20];
    let bands = rastertools.isobands(data, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], intervals);

    let colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBuPu);

    let canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", 680)
    .attr("height", 500);

    let context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

    let path = d3.geoPath()
                 .context(context);

    bands.features.forEach(function(d, i) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
      path(d);
      context.fill();
      console.log(context)
  });

})();


</script>
</body>
```